# How to define higher power of polynomials in equation of objective in Gurobi?

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to add polynomials of different powers in my objective equation. I tried using Python's `math.pow` in the equation but it didn't work. Following is my code:

```py
modal = Model("modal")

temp = modal.addVar(-26,48, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = "temp")

EC = gurobi.QuadExpr(math.exp(7e-7)*math.pow(temp,6) - math.exp(9e-5)*math.pow(temp,5) + 0.0022*math.pow(temp,4) + 0.0887*math.pow(temp,3)- 0.5655*pow(temp,2) - 69.606*temp + 4979.7)

mAggresive.setObjective(EC + EUC + ELAggresive, GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gurobi can only handle (some) quadratic forms. Of course x^6 is the same as:

```
x2 = x^2
x4 = x2^2
x6 = x4*x2
```

This looks ok, but typically things have to be convex. That means we can't have quadratic equality constraints. In some cases you can convert things into inequalities but in general Gurobi cannot handle what you want.

Of course an alternative is to use a piecewise linear approximation. Gurobi has facilities to make this somewhat easy.

Comment: I see. Thanks for guidance